# Facebook App setup to require User & Friend Permissions email, but using app for first time the email access is not asked for

Tags: facebook, email

I have setup a facebook app to be used with our application. WE require the email address from the user, so i have setup this in the app center as email (User & Friend Permissions).
However when our web app directs to the facebook app for the first time we see all the usual dialogs,
but the email address is not stated. 
The end result is that i cannot gain access to the users email address.

Hope anyone can help or point me in the right direction

Answer (score 1):

"when our web app directs to the facebook app for the first time we see all the usual dialogs" - do you mean the user is landing on your website, and you are using either the FB.login() method from the JS SDK or redirecting the user to the oauth dialog?

If so, you need to specify the permissions you require from the user when you invoke authentication.

1. Pass the required permissions in the 'scope' parameter to FB.login(): https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/
2. Specify the required permissions in the scope parameter when redirecting to the oauth dialog: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/client-side/#no-jssdk

The settings you supply for permissions in the App Center only apply to users who install your app from your app detail page.

Answer (score 0):

Add 'email' in users permission..

using this  User & Friend Permissions: https://developers.facebook.com/apps/APPID/auth